# Unreported IOException error, but has "throws Exception" and Try and Catch is within method

Tags: java, exception

I created a Util class that returns an array that is based on a file. When I try to instantiate this array object in the Statistics class, I get this error:

error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

I have both a throws IOException and try and catch. A similar stack overflow question was solved by placing the try and catch inside of the action method, but mine seems to have that already.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Util:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Util {
   public static Student[] readFile(String fileName) throws IOException  {
         Student studentArray[]=new Student[15];
         try{
            FileReader file = new FileReader("studentData.txt");
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(file);
            String line;
            line = buff.readLine();
            int index=0;
            while(line != null){
               System.out.println(line);
               if(index>14){
                  break;
               }
               line = buff.readLine();
               String[] result = line.split("\\s");
               int sid = Integer.parseInt(result[0]);
               int scores[] = new int[5];
               for(int x=1;x<result.length;x++){
                  scores[x-1] = Integer.parseInt(result[x]);
               }
               Student myCSC20Student = new Student(sid, scores);
               studentArray[index++] = myCSC20Student;
            }
         }
         catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
         } 
         return studentArray;  
      }    
   }
```

Statistics:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Statistics {
   final int LABS = 5;
   public int[] lowscores = new int[LABS];
   private int[] highscores = new int[LABS];
   private float[] avgscores = new float[LABS];
   public static void main(String args[]) {
   Student[] studArr = Util.readFile("studentData.txt") ;
   System.out.println(studArr[1]);
   }
   void calculateLow(Student[] a){

   }
   void calculateHigh(Student[] a){

   }
   void calculateAvg(Student[] a){

   }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your `Reader`s. You can do this either by converting to a `try-with-resources` or adding a `finally` block after `catch` and add `reader.close()`

Answer (score 1):

You've marked `readFile` as throwing IOException, so anywhere you use that method, you need to wrap it in a `try-catch` block.

With your current code, I would suggest removing the `throws` portion of the method, because you're catching it anyway. What I suggest you do is remove the `try-catch` in the method and leave that to the callers. I recommend this because it makes it simpler to catch errors as opposed to the returned array just being empty.

Answer (score 0):

You have already added try catch block in **Util** class so no need to throws the IOException. Remove throws clause from **readFile** method in Util class.

Answer (score 0):

readFile() declares IOException. This means that anywhere it's called, must also declare IOException, or catch it. In this case, readFile() does not need to declare IOException because it's caught within the method.

However, a larger issue is that you're calling an IO oriented method in class initialization. This makes it very difficult to deal with actual exceptions sanely. At the very least, your readFile() should return null or an empty array in the event of an exception.

In short, don't declare IOException on readFile().